# ListView - check values before displaying

Tags: asp.net, webforms

is it possible to check the value in a ListView?

I want to do something like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" 
                DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True">

                <ItemTemplate>

                  if <%# Eval("Id") == X %>
                       "do something"
                  else
                       "do something else"

                </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should, but try:

```
<% if (Eval("Id") == X) { %>
                       "do something"
<% }  else { %>
                       "do something else"
<% } %>
```

If that doesn't work, most people use the tertiary syntax as in:

```
<%= (Eval("Id") == X) ? "do something" : "do something else" %>
```

Something like that.

HTH.